# How to hide longer text in select box and wrap it when showing it as a option

Tags: javascript, html, css, text, drop-down-menu

How do I hide longer text in select box and wrap it when showing it as an option?

Basically, when an option in a select box has longer text it should not display but it should have some indication or sign to say that there is more text, which should be shown when looking at select box options.

So is there any javascript to manage lengthy text options in select box?

Comment: You will need to use a custom select box with help of jQuery/javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this function:

```
// shorten_options( selectElement[, max_length] );
function shorten_options(elem, max) {
    var options = elem.options, op, i;
    max = max ? max - 3 : 7;
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i += 1) {
        op = options[i];
        if (op.textContent.length > max) {
            op.textContent = op.textContent.substring(0, max) + '...';
        }
    }
}
```

Just pass it a 'select' element and a max length.

You could modify this to your liking by checking the selectedIndex and remembering the values.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to try out **[CHOSEN](http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/)** jQuery Plugin for all your dropdown options as it has great functionality and options.

Comment: I have tried this chosen plugin looks great but could not find the lengthy text showing ... in the end and when showing the lengthy text in options show all the text but wrap it around. could you please help me with that bit, is that possible?